# Set timeout for big query

Tags: c#, timeout, sqlconnection

I'm having a stored procedure looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.BigTable 
FOR XML PATH, ELEMENTS XSINIL, ROOT('data')
```

The stored procedure takes a lot more time then 3 seconds, but it's still processing everything and doesn't get a timeout. If I put WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:04' then the timeout works fine.

How can I set a properly timeout so that reading the results never exceeds the timeout limit? Why do I not get a timeout here?

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(tycheCon))
{
     con.Open();
     using (var sqlCmd = con.CreateCommand())
     {
          sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          sqlCmd.CommandText = dbo.spGetData;
          sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 3;

          using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
          {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   //Do stuff with result
               }
               reader.Close();
          }
     }
     con.Close();
}
```

EDIT:

Connectionstring looks like:

> Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=CoolName

Comment: What you written looks pretty fine. Are you looking for a way to elegantly wrap the statement where you have written sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 3 ?

Comment: @Kapoor Not sure...I Just wan't my code to timeout when query takes longer time then 3 seconds (which it does)..

Comment: And what u have written is not working?

Comment: I've missed a line in my stored procedure which I think is the problem..

Comment: Let me make a test today... And I'll inform u if I find something helpful

Comment: Thank you. I Can see that the query it self takes around 1 second, but with FOR XML PATH (...) it takes about 9 seconds, and when converting the result set to xml doesn't seems to be included in the timeout :)